# React Native init specific version

Tags: ios, react-native

I upgraded my latest project to React Native 0.19 and instantly the video no longer works. How can I create a new project with a specific version? I want to init a new project at version 0.18.1. I did some google searches but couldn't find anything about this.

```
$ react-native init newproject --verbose
```

I'm guessing I need to add the word @18.1 in there somewhere but can't get that to work.

Comment: You could use the initialized project, delete the node_modules, then go into the package.json file and specify the version you want, and run npm insall again.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help.

Comment: I would *not* recommend this approach as there could be changes to the native Xcode and Android projects which won't get applied if you only change the React Native version in `package.json`

Answer (score 227, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$ react-native init newproject --version X.XX.X
```

Comment: @Polygon I agreed but it was added more than 1.5 years after my answer so I guess that's why it hasn't received as many upvotes.

Comment: I wonder if it will rename the project as there is a name or it will simply and wrongly start off a new one with newproject name

Comment: Add a link to the **RN** [offical document](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#optional-using-a-specific-version-or-template)

Answer (score 42):

```
$ react-native init projectname --version 0.56.0
```

please check this guide
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
[image]

Comment: This works with new versions now, and this is the standard method.

Comment: But it shows `Need to install the following packages:
  react-native@0.71.4`

Answer (score 11):

I have tried all the answers given in this post but most of them are not working
So, I followed the official documentation, and here is the answer to this question:

```
npx react-native@X.XX.X init ProjectNameHere --version X.XX.X
```

**where X is your specific version.**

Comment: this a better answer because the original answer doesn't include version after `@` which was giving me issues. With that version specified everything works as expected: https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup#optional-using-a-specific-version-or-template

Answer (score 9):

#### Version and Template

Currently, I'm having problems with the `0.60.0` version so for doing this with version and typescript it goes like this:

```
react-native init ProjectName --version="0.59.9" --template="typescript"
```

This has 2 unwanted side effects:

1. devDependencies will be the latest but the dependencies will be the chosen, this will work anyway after...
2. You will get a `react-native/libraries/NewAppScreen` error, go to `App.tsx` and replace all of that for something simple like a `<View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'orange'}}>` so you can see it running

Answer (score 8):

```
react-native init appname --version="0.63.4"
```

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work.

`react-native init --version="0.36.0" MyNewApp`

Check the comment on this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4723#issuecomment-270908269) :).

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
react-native init YourProjectName --version X.XX.X
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

npx react-native init YOURPROJECTNAME --version X.XX.X

Answer (score 2):

Run this:

```
npx react-native@0.72.1 init ProjectName --version 0.72.1
```

Answer (score 1):

react-native init Yout_Project_Name --version 0.63.3

Answer (score -2):

react-native init newApp --version 0.62.0

Comment: What does this add to the already existing answers?