# React Native CLI version for Xcode 9.2

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-cli

I had followed the instructions on installing React Native from the official website.
After doing as instructed, when I run the code, I get a error and after some research I found out it is because I am still using a 2011 MAC BOOK PRO and the Xcode version I am using is Xcode 9.2 which is not really compatible with the current version of React Native.

I would like to use the old version of React Native.  Which React Native version is compatible with Xcode 9.2 and which React Native CLI version should I be using?

I tried installing the old version using the CLI by:

```
react-native init Test --version 0.51
```

But I get the following error:

> This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in
>   /Users/bliss/Documents/Coder/ReactNative/Test Using yarn v1.3.2
>   Installing 0.51... yarn add v1.3.2 info No lockfile found. [1/4]  
>   Resolving packages... error An unexpected error occurred:
>   "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/0.51: Not found". info If you think this
>   is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in
>   "/Users/bliss/Documents/Coder/ReactNative/Test/yarn-error.log". info
>   Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this
>   command. { Error: Command failed: yarn add 0.51 --exact
>       at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
>       at execSync (child_process.js:666:13)
>       at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:294:5)
>       at createProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:249:3)
>       at init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:200:5)
>       at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:153:7)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)   status: 1,   signal: null,   output: [ null, null, null ],   pid: 6231,
>   stdout: null,   stderr: null } Command `yarn add 0.51 --exact` failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you are giving in the version is in the wrong way.

As you can see in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started#optional-using-a-specific-version-1) it should be

```
react-native init AwesomeProject --version X.XX.X
```

Instead of `0.51` try `0.51.0`.

You can also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110363/react-native-init-specific-version) where there is alot of answer and other ways of doing it.